# Model::Create() method not inserting with InnoDB storage engine

Tags: mysql, laravel, innodb, myisam

I am trying to insert a new record `customer` into `MySQL` database as following:

```
$customer = Customer::create(['name'=>$request->customerName,
'email'=>$request->customerEmail,
'phone'=>$request->customerPhone,
'area_id'=>$request->customerArea,
'gender'=>$request->customerGender]);
dd($customer->id);
```

It works well with `myISAM` storage engine and a new record is there, but not working with `InnoDB`, the post request returns `200` with no record in the database. While the dump `dd()` returns the new `ID` as it's auto incremented. The `ID` is taken already, as when I insert a new record it gives me a newer ID than previous one, with no record in the database also.

[image: 200 Response]

[image: New ID]

Here's Customer model structure:

```
namespace App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone', 'email', 'area_id', 'gender'
    ];

    protected $table = 'customers';
}
```

And here's `customers` table structure:

[image: Customers table structure]

Comment: did u try with save() instead?

Comment: @JahStation, same issue with save()

Comment: i dont think is 100% related but id shiuld be declared bigint (bigincrementes for migrations), with this kind of problem i use to run another query over the db for gettin the new id.

Comment: Have you confirmed by querying, that the rows are not inserted, vs an issue with phpmyadmin not displaying them?

Comment: @levi, Yes, confirmed, the IDs are taken but not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using InnoDB, you need to know at least a little about "transactions".

If you have `autocommit=ON`, each statement (such as `INSERT`) will be a transaction unto itself and will be automatically `COMMITTed`.

If you have `autocommit=OFF`, you must eventually issue `COMMIT`.  This is because the statements (`INSERTs`, etc) are being collected in a "transaction".

The latter case fits the symptoms.

Comment: You're right, that works as I forgot to commit the transaction.

Comment: And for that very reason, I never use `autocommit=OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created your `Customer` model, why don't you use it directly like this :

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = $request->customerName;
$customer->email = $request->customerEmail;
$customer->phone = $request->customerPhone;
$customer->area_id = $request->customerArea;
$customer->gender = $request->customerGender;
$customer->save();
```

PS. Don't forget, of course, to import your `Customer` model into your **controller**

Comment: I tried this method, but same problem, not inserting.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly noted your **database** in the **.env** file ?

Comment: Of course I did, that's why it inserts with myISAM.

Comment: Is the **type** of your **Customers table** = **InnoDB** ?

Comment: Yes, storage engine is InnoDB for Customers table.